# Drag and drop of files not working on version 22.04

Tags: xorg, wayland, drag-and-drop

I installed ubuntu 22.04 LTS using the live bootable image. I am unable to send files by dragging and droping into the various application.
But when I use xOrg, the problem seems to disappear. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give examples on "dragging and droping into the various application"?

Comment: Thanks for respose Like in the edge browser, I use web.whatsapp.com and want to transfer file, by dragging the file and dropping in the window, but its donot works, nothing happened

Comment: Yeah for me it's from IntelliJ Idea I can't anymore drag'n drop files to external folders. I think It's wayland because it seems before (20.04) I used probably xOrg because of multiple small issues with wayland

Comment: I can confirm the same behavior. Upgrading from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS today. Firefox (running as snap since 22.04) fails to drag and drop cards on trello.com. With xOrg, the problem is not present.

Comment: I've installed [MATE Desktop](https://gcore.com/learning/how-to-install-mate-on-ubuntu/) environment, on Ubuntu 22.04, and Drag and Drop run perfectly

Answer (score 6):

Using Brave or Edge or Chrome browser since upgrading to 22.04 drag and drop to a file upload pane does not work 95% of the time. Sometimes it works the first time you try it in a session.

This happens across a wide range of websites, all of which worked correctly with these browsers before the upgrade.

It can be fixed by disabling Wayland and using X11 instead - this restores normal functionality.

Clearly a Wayland problem but I can't report it as a bug on ubuntu because when I run the tool it says I don't have Wayland installed - because it is disabled and I'm not about to re-enable it because it is VERY flakey and is causing multiple problems.

Perhaps someone more competent than me can report it as a bug. My recommendation would be that the use of Wayland as a default should be reversed to re-enable X11 by default as Wayland seems to be causing many problems.

This is going to negatively impact Ubuntu and re-inforce the "Linux only suitable for techie nerds" label that I thought we had left behind.

In the meantime if you make sure you know your user password and logout, and then start to login again, when the password box appears there is a little gear icon at the bottom right of the screen - click on it and it will offer you the choice of Wayland or Xorg (X11) - select X11 and it will remember the setting for that user and multiple problems will disappear.

There seems to be no practical advantage to using Wayland, some applications like Eclipse run much faster using X11 - essentially you get your old 20.04 machine back again which just works.

Comment: The OP reported in comment that his problem lies with web.whatsapp.com does your answer address that?

Comment: The OP says "various applications". A specific example he gave when asked in a comment was Edge browser when viewing the WhatsApp website. I suggest (as he implied in the OP) that it is wider than just one website and may affect much any browser that is not fully wayland compatible. Possibly due to settings saved under 20.04 and not automatically updated to 22.04. So while there may be a specific fix for each browser or other malfunctioning application involving uninstalling and re-installing with Wayland in use, a more pragmatic solution is simply to disable Wayland and use X11 instead.

Comment: This is something that I experiece too with every sort of applications, starting from the File Explorer (Nautilus ??) to content inside a website (e.g. Notion). Now the latter seems mostly connected to Firefox that I have decided to adopt as a primary browser. Using Chrome I can move things within the site, but when it comes to drag and drop from a file explorer to a site like dropbox, this - more often than not - doesn't work irrespectively from the browser, so there must be something else. E.g. I struggle a lot when I have to archive my photos

Comment: After performing a dist-upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS I also noticed that drag & drop was very unreliable. At times it worked, other times it didn't but as I am mainly developing a VSC plugin currently I though it had something to do with a bug in VSC. After upgrading to the latest version though the "bug" was still there and so I learned through this answer that 22.04 changed to Wayland and could lead to drag & drop acting strange. After changing to X11 drag & drop now works as expected. Only downside is, one of my monitors now addresses wrong colors for some reasons ...

Comment: Confirming it's a Wayland issue. Could not extract folder from a zip in nautilus by drag and drop. Logged out then logged in selecting "Ubuntu on xorg" and drag and drop works correctly. Also in brave and chrome where could not upload stuff by drag and drop for a week since I upgraded to 22.04

Answer (score 3):

As others have hinted, it is a permission issue.

Opening folders with `sudo nautilus /home/user/` or `sudo xdg-open /home/user/` fixes this.

Comment: This works but it's a terrible UX..

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is caused by a bug in 'mutter', ref [issue 2216](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2216)
There seems to be a merge request, but the issue is still open.
I guess I will use the xOrg version until this is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to 22.04, and much sweat over previous wxPython programs not running, and - worst of all - TKinter drag and drop not working, I discovered the problem is Wayland.

Using the above advice, and logging back in using the gear selector on the right bottom of the logon screen and selecting X11, the wxPython problems went away and Tkinter drag and drop works perfectly fine.

Could have done with some more obvious information about this problem with Wayland!

Answer (score 0):

I use web.whatsapp.com under `Firefox` with ubuntu 20.04 and I think it is not ubuntu related but web.whatsapp itself that causes the issue. When I try it, the error report is

> Drag and drop is not supported an invalid drag type was used

but right clicking the image in whatsapp and copy/paste works fine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is more than just a permissions issue. I use WhatSie, which appears to be a container to run WhatsApp Web, and with it, I am -- apparently -- only able to upload documents and images from within the /home directory -- which is, BTW, also the same problem with Snaps.

My workflow proceeds from a /development directory, which is "cannon" across the various desktops, laptops, and the like that I work on. I don't always use the same username everywhere, nor should I have to. And the one on my desktop at work is assigned by policy... well you know how that goes.

Since we are talking Ubuntu here, this was a continual problem I ran into with Snap applications. And Canonical seems to want to run all applications out of snaps, including the browsers.

Only file permissions and ownership should matter, not whether it's running out of /home.

I approached the developers behind Snap a few years back, and they indicated that it's a "known problem", and they would "get around" to "addressing it" later. A very genteel blow-off, if I ever saw one.

So I dropped Ubuntu and went to Arch, with a very brief step though Manjaro -- only because so many were bitching that installing Arch was "hard".

When I installed Arch on this new system I built using the latest motherboard, Threadripper, and all, only Arch worked. Manjaro (and Ubuntu) failed to install at the time. That made an impression on me. And installing Arch was staightforward, as it is well-documented on the Arch Wiki.+

But I digress.

Not looking to start an rwar over Snaps. If it works for you and you don't mind it cluttering up your device lists with all those loop devices, one per application, and it keeping you jailed at /home, go for it.

But I prefer a cleaner experience.