# Drag and Drop for Eclipse not Working Correctly in 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, eclipse

Since I've updated to Ubuntu 22.04 (with everything set to default, just the regular Gnome desktop), drag & drop in eclipse does not work as expected.

Normally, I can drag a `.java` file. If I drop it to the empty ground, I have two windows opened, like this:
[image]
Afterwards, I could move other `.java` files to the new window (in this example, by dragging `TeetimeConfiguration.java` and dropping it to the window containing `LogsReaderCompositeStage.java`). Unfortunately, this does not work anymore, the second window does not react any longer (and dropping there results in the file going back to the original window). I can drop it to the empty space (creating a third eclipse window), but not to the existing window (which should produce two tabs in the same window).

This was working with Ubuntu 20.04 and is working with Fedora, so I assume that this is something caused by the update to 22.04.

It seems to be similiar to [Drag and drop of files not working on version 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421539/drag-and-drop-of-files-not-working-on-version-22-04), but I don't see a fix there. It seems to me like just some right is missing for the eclipse window. Is there some configuration / workaround to fix this?

Comment: I've added an issue to the eclipse UI: https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/issues/855

Comment: This seems to be caused by wayland, as for other applications: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714305/unable-to-drag-and-drop-files-into-other-applications-on-ubuntu-22-04 Switching to xorg works, but is not a good permanent solution.